# Условия в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как  можно сделать условия если в "input field" выводится значения 10100 и нажимается Enter то всплывает значок "Button" чтобы перейти в другой уровень а если значения не 10100 и нажимается Enter то поля "input field" очищается (Unity,C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class JustAScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;
    public InputField inputField;

    void Start()
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void InputFunction(string input)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            if (int.Parse(input) == 10100)
            {
                button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                inputField.text = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Потом прикрепите функцию вот так:

[image]